# Change datasource of multiple layers from one db to other db in QGIS project?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, qgis-3

I have a QGIS project with around 100 layers referring to a postgres database.

Since we're migrating to a new server, the database will be transfered too, but will be given a new IP. The connection between all layers in my QGIS project will be lost, due to a slight alteration in the source connection.

***Is there a way to change the datasource of all layers, instead of the need to refer to this new db, layer by layer?***

(Extra info: the way how the postgres database is structured isn't changing, the IP is the only thing being changed.)

Comment: Hi ThomasG77 and thanks for sharing your snippet of code! I used it but, unfortunatley, the layer uri do not persist in the project. After running code, in python console uri and newUri are the same. If I save the project, on the contrary, the newUri is not saved! Have you any ideas? Thanks in advance Fabrizio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know at least 2 ways to do it

- Do a search and replace. For this intent, close the project. If it's a qgz file , rename it to qgs.gz and open the archive to find a qgs file. Edit it in place by researching the old ip and do a search and replace. Then, rename your qgs.gz to qgz and open in QGIS
- PyQGIS

```py
your_host = 'your_new_ip'
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()

for layer in layers:
    if layer.dataProvider().name() == 'postgres':
        provider = layer.dataProvider()
        uri = provider.uri()
        newUri = QgsDataSourceUri()
        newUri.setConnection(your_host, uri.port(), uri.database(), uri.username(), uri.password())
        newUri.setDataSource (uri.schema(), uri.table(), uri.geometryColumn())
        provider.setDataSourceUri(newUri.uri())
        provider.reloadData()
```

On the long term, I would use a pg_service.conf file to declare the database infos outside your QGIS project. See https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html#service-connection-file (old doc but always working)

Comment: Search & replace would be my suggestion, too.

Comment: Grr, that I didn't think of using find/replace myself! Thanks anyway :-)
Your suggestion for the long term seems interesting, but it would store db passwords in an unencrypted way?